# Cyclic quotient group of permutation group $\mathbb{S}_n$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

I have a group-theoretic lemma that I am having difficulty with:

### $\mathbb{S}_n$ has a cyclic quotient group of prime order $p$ iff $p=2$ and $n\geq2$

Proof:
$n=2$ is trivial so suppose $n\geq3$.

Let $N\trianglelefteq G$ and suppose $\mathbb{S}_n/N\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ which is Abelian.
By nature of $N$, $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\in N$ for $g,h\in\mathbb{S}_n$.

**jump in logic**

Let $g,h$ be 2-cycles i.e. $g=(ab)$ and $h=(ac)$ for a,b,c distinct. Thus,
$$ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=(bca)$$
is a 3-cycle and all possible 3-cycles can be obtained this way. Therefore $N$ contains all 3-cycles. Since 3-cycles generate $\mathbb{A}_n$, $N \subseteq \mathbb{A}_n$

**jump in logic**

$\therefore p=2$ since $|\mathbb{S}_n/\mathbb{A}_n|=2$

Question 1: Why are we picking 2-cycles in particular? Are they picked because they construct the 3-cycles to be used later in the proof?

Question 2: How are concluding that $\mathbb{A}_n\subseteq N$? If we    are not using this, how is the jump in logic explained?

---

P.S.
I cannot use the property that $\mathbb{A}_n$ is simple for $n\neq4$

Comment: The facts $N$ contains all $3$-cycles and that $3$-cycles generate $A_n$ imply that $A_n \le N$, not that $N \le A_n$.

Comment: That is quite counter-intuitive... especially since the book I'm following says otherwise.

Comment: @Malcolm Let's begin from the fact that if you assume $N$ contains a $2$-cycle then there is no chance for $N\leq A_n$. So for sure you did something wrong here. Next, if $N$ contains all $3$ cycles then it must contain $A_n$ because $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles.

Comment: @Mark Okay that makes sense. But then, how does the last 'jump in logic' work if we are not assuming $N=A_n$ (as I thought it continued)?

Comment: If $A_n\leq N$ then $N=A_n$ or $N=S_n$, there are no other options. But your assumption is that $S_n/N$ has prime order, hence $N$ can't be equal to $S_n$. Anyway, the proof looks strange to me. Some parts are very unclear.

Comment: That's a really good argument! Thank you!

Comment: I also recommend to take a look at the answer Soumik Ghosh wrote, it is a much more clear proof of why $S_n$ can't have any quotient groups of odd prime order.

Comment: @Mark, the proof kind of goes over my head a bit. 'Trivial' is a subjective notion.

Comment: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then there is a projection $\pi:G\to G/N$ defined by $g\to gN$. This is a surjective homomorphism. So in his answer he explains why such a map can't be surjective if the order of $G/N$ is an odd prime.

Comment: I also got tricked by the typo in Ian Stewart's Galois Theory book. It should have been $A_n \subseteq N$ but it is written $N \subseteq A_n$. Thank you for asking this question, since I also started searching when I did not understand the proof there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial because of the following. So assume there exists a surjection $G\rightarrow \mathbb Z_p$ where $p\neq2$. Then since the order of any transposition is $2$ it goes to $0$ in the image. But transpositions generate $S_n;n\geq2$ and hence $Im$ $G=0$ which contradicts surjectivity.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: Thank you for your enlightful answer. @Mark, thank you for explaining his answer for me as well. I have written my own version of both your comments and referenced your well thought out answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the insight provided by Soumik Ghosh's answer and the extremely clear explanation by Mark, I have managed to translate the quite clever proof into something that I can understand quite simply.

By our hypothesis, $\pi:\mathbb{S}_n\to \mathbb{S}_n/N \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, for $p \neq 2$.

Since $\mathbb{S}_n$ is generated by transpositions, then any permutation $s=t_1t_2\cdots t_n$ where $t_i$ are transpositions.

However, for $N \trianglelefteq \mathbb{S}_n$,  $\pi:\mathbb{S}_n\to \mathbb{S}_n/N$ is a surjective homomorphism so $\forall g\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\exists s\in\mathbb{S}_n$ s.t. $\pi(s)=g$.

This implies that $g^2=(\pi(s))^2=\pi(t_1)\cdots\pi(t_n)\pi(t_1)\cdots\pi(t_n)$.

But $\pi$ is abelian so $g^2=\pi(t_1^2)\cdots\pi(t_n^2)=\pi(1)=1$. But every element g is of order $p\neq2$. Contradiction!

Comment: I can also prove along the same lines that if $A_n$ has a cyclic quotient group of prime order, then that prime must be 3 :)!

Comment: Your proof is almost perfect. Only in the end where you wrote "every element $g$ is of order $p$" you should add "except the identity". So by picking any $g$ which is not the identity we have $g^2\ne 1$ and this is a contradiction.